# Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex, alphabetic

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

With `biblatex`, `alphabetic` style, I have

> <author>. <title>

But I want to have a colon ":" instead of the period "." after the author:

> <author>: <title>

What do I have to change?

Comment: I refurbished your question a bit, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put the following in your preamble after having loaded **biblatex**

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

(This is better than `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{:\addspace}`, as remarked by domwass.)

---

**Update**

The `\labelnamepunct` command is currently deprecated and the context dependent

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

should be used. However, old styles *may* still be using `\labelnamepunct`, so the original answer has been kept. (Thanks to moewe for recalling to update.)

Comment: It would be better to use `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}`, because then unintended whitespace before the colon will be deleted.

Comment: @domwass Right; all those `\add...` commands in **biblatex** are confusing.

Comment: This works with `verbose` style as well. Question: The `\labelnamepunct` will only be executed after the author entry and nowhere else?

Comment: @doncherry `biblatex` defines many "punct" commands, so I guess this is specialized for that purpose.

Comment: @ItsmeJulian Do you think there is a global option to begin with?

Comment: @add: global option delimter between units or blocks: `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
%\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{,\addspace}
%\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{,\addspace}` (This is what I was lookin for, yay)

Comment: @moewe Done as requested

Comment: Merci! ........