# Period after last author name in biblatex when terseinits = true

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

My reference style requires author initials without period-space but between the author list and year there should be a period, e.g.

> Cho JC, Kim MW, Lee DH, Kim SJ. (1997). Response of bacterial communities to changes in composition of extracellular organic carbon from phytoplankton in Daechung reservoir (Korea). Arch Hydrobiol 138:559–576.

Trouble is that author and year are produced together using `\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}` which is a basic biblatex macro.

Any tips on how to modify that?

p.s
for some reason the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/colon-instead-of-period-after-author-with-biblatex-alphabetic) using `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{}` doesn't seem to work in my case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to patch the `date+extrayear` bibmacro. (The solution is a slight modification of [biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits=true,terseinits=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. A. and Buthor, B. B. and Cuthor, C. C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, what an overkill for such a seemingly simple task. But hey, it works like a charm so who am I to complain.

Comment: I'm guessing the author never expected anyone to want punctuation between the name list and the year. The period does look weird IMO. A slightly shorter solution is `\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}{}{}`.

Comment: Also in my opinion, but no less weird are the minds of people who decide on these citation styles for the various journals.

Comment: `extrayear` has been deprecated and replaced by `extradate` [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428190/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style-v). The solution by @lockstep still works if `\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}` is replaced by `\xpretobibmacro{date+extradate}`