# Add period after author in biblatex with dashed entries

Tags: biblatex

I need to add a period after the (last) author in my bibliography, right before the printed year. From [Period after last author name in biblatex when terseinits = true](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83982/period-after-last-author-name-in-biblatex-when-terseinits-true) I learned that I can do this with

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}{}{}
```

But when the `biblatex` option `dashed` is set to `true`, and there are multiple entries within one year so that the letters `a` and `b` are added to separate them, the period is added after the year inside the parentheses instead of going after the dash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, dashed = true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}{}{}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Does she love you? Yeah, yeah, yeah",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Top of the Pops",
    YEAR = "1963",
    PAGES = "5--13"}
@article{lennon1967a,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "A day in whose life?",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Top of the Pops",
    YEAR = "1967",
    PAGES = "12--24"}
@article{lennon1967b,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Is love all you need?",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Top of the Pops",
    YEAR = "1967",
    PAGES = "25--34"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the dash is printed, if so we do not add the period, otherwise we print it.

```
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\space}}}
  {}{}
```

---

However, I think in this case a long solution is the most robust one. (You see how fickle the patching makes the macros.)

We replace some `\setunit{\addspace}` by `\setunit{\addperiod\space}` in the `author`, `bbx:editor` and `bbx:translator` macros:

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addperiod\space}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\adddperiod\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}


\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addperiod\space}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addperiod\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}


\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\addperiod\space}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, dashed = true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Does she love you? Yeah, yeah, yeah",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Top of the Pops",
    YEAR = "1963",
    PAGES = "5--13"}
@article{lennon1967a,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "A day in whose life?",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Top of the Pops",
    YEAR = "1967",
    PAGES = "12--24"}
@article{lennon1967b,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Is love all you need?",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Top of the Pops",
    YEAR = "1967",
    PAGES = "25--34"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addperiod\space}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\adddperiod\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}


\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addperiod\space}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addperiod\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}


\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\addperiod\space}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To include a period after the dash, go with

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{0.75em}
    {\mbox{\textemdash\addperiod\space}}
    {\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{%
       \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{1.25em}
         {\textendash\addperiod}
         {\textemdash\addperiod}}}}
```

This just adds `\addperiod` after the different dashes.

Comment: How easy would it be to implement an added period after the dash, i.e. ``-. (1967a).``? It's not crucial, I guess, but the journal style sheet does indicate it ... :-/

Comment: @Sverre I guess, one could just modify the `\bibnamedash` command to include the period. See edit.

Comment: That works, except that there is no space after the period, so it prints ``-.(1967a)`` rather than ``-. (1967a)``. I tried just adding ``\addspace`` and ``\space`` after ``\addperiod`` in your code, but nothing happened ...

Comment: @Sverre I do think there is a space between the period and the parentheses, my pdf reader even lets me select one. If you insist on more space, add a `\space` just before the last curly brace in the redefinition above.

Comment: You're right. It does add a space in this MWE, but it doesn't when I added your code to my style sheet ``.sty`` file. I'll try to find the culprit line in my ``.sty`` file that causes this.

Comment: @Sverre Maybe there is some `\unspace` in your code. Check also if you have a redefinition of `\bibnamedash`.

Comment: Haven't found the culprit yet. There's no ``\unspace``, and ``\bibnamedash`` only appears in your code. If you'd care to look, my ``.sty`` file is at http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02174304992697248236. Your code is at the end.

Comment: @Sverre I cannot find any obvious problem there, what happens if you add the `\space` as I suggested above, would you be OK with that?

Comment: Sorry I missed that suggestion. And yes, that does work! :)