# Styling \citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use this code for my citations:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliography{biblio}
\addbibresource{references/biblio.bib}
```

At the moment the citation of @book references looks like this:

```
@book{Kundegraber2008, 
    title={ Verlan 2007. Untersuchungen zur französischen Jugendsprache.},
    author={Kundegraber, Angela},
    year={2008},
    publisher={ Kovac },
    address={Hamburg}
}
```

> Kundegraber, Angela (2008). *Verlan 2007. Untersuchungen zur französischen Jugendsprache*. Hamburg: Kovac.

What I need is, that after the 'year' there is a colon instead of the dot. So that it looks like this:

> Kundegraber, Angela (2008): *Verlan 2007. Untersuchungen zur französischen Jugendsprache*. Hamburg: Kovac.

Then there is one more special thing I need. I got some @article references like this:

```
@article{Androutsopoulos,
  author  = {Androutsopoulos, Jannis K. and Scholz (Hrsg.), Arno}, 
  title   = {Linguistische und soziolinguistische Perspektiven},
  journal = {Vario Lingua Band 7.}, % author: Albrecht, Jörn (Hrsg.) u.a.
  number = { Frankfurt am Main, Berlin, New York, Paris, Wien, Lang.},
  year = {1998}
}
```

At the moment it is shown like this:

> Androutsopoulos, Jannis K. und Arno Scholz (Hrsg.) (1998). „Linguistische und soziolinguisti- sche Perspektiven“. In: *Vario Lingua Band 7*. Frankfurt am Main, Berlin, New York, Paris, Wien, Lang.

Here there also needs to be the colon instead of the dot and there is the **".In: "** which tells in which journal the article is posted. But I want it to be like **", in:"**. And I also have some articles like this one, where I want to mention the authors of the journal. (see the comment in the reference above). So I think the reference needs to be changed too. So this one should look like this (where the journal author is **not** in italic font):

> Androutsopoulos, Jannis K. und Arno Scholz (Hrsg.) (1998): „Linguistische und soziolinguisti- sche Perspektiven“, in: Albrecht, Jörn (Hrsg.) u.a.: *Vario Lingua Band 7*. Frankfurt am Main, Berlin, New York, Paris, Wien, Lang.

These are very specific needs and I don't know how to achieve that. Can anyone help me here? Thanks!

Comment: For future references: It is often easier to answer questions if they include [a full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) instead of just a few snippets of code we have to piece together ourselves. Please note also that normally we prefer to ask one question per question (that makes it easier for other people to find answers as well as fr those who want to answer), you seem to ask more than that.

Comment: BTW: I don't actually think VarioLingua is really a journal. Journals rarely have editors you give in the bibliography. It looks more like a series of monographs (`@book` -> `@inbook`) or collections (`@collection` -> `@incollection`).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the colon with

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

(See also [Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex, alphabetic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28892/35864))

Your second entry is not actually an `@article`, according to http://pub.ids-mannheim.de/extern/vario/vl07.html it is a `@collection` and should probably look like this

```
@collection{androutsopoulos1,
  editor    = {Androutsopoulos, Jannis and Scholz, Arno}, 
  title     = {Jugendsprache -- langue des jeunes -- youth language},
  subtitle  = {Linguistische und soziolinguistische Perspektiven},
  year      = {1998},
  publisher = {Lang},
  location  = {Frankfurt am Main},
  series    = {VarioLingua},
  number    = {7},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kundegraber2008, 
  title     = {Verlan 2007},
  subtitle  = {Untersuchungen zur französischen Jugendsprache},
  author    = {Kundegraber, Angela},
  year      = {2008},
  publisher = {Kovač},
  location  = {Hamburg},
}
@collection{androutsopoulos1,
  editor    = {Androutsopoulos, Jannis and Scholz, Arno}, 
  title     = {Jugendsprache -- langue des jeunes -- youth language},
  subtitle  = {Linguistische und soziolinguistische Perspektiven},
  year      = {1998},
  publisher = {Lang},
  location  = {Frankfurt am Main},
  series    = {VarioLingua},
  number    = {7},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{kundegraber2008,androutsopoulos1,androutsopoulos2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```