# Making authoryear citation style bold with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

My university authority requires a bold author-year citation style with also a bold bibliography author-year style including the author(s) and year
I am not an expert in biblatex and need your help. Included a minimum working example but without any attempts to apply what is required.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={}]{hyperref}
%=====================================================
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\mybib.bib}
@Article{caton1989periodontal,
  author  = {Caton, J},
  title   = {Periodontal diagnosis and diagnostic aids: consensus report in Proceedings of the World Workshop in Clinical Periodontics},
  journal = {American Academy of Periodontology},
  year    = {1989},
}
@Book{williams1992pathology,
  author    = {Williams, D.M.},
  title     = {Pathology of Periodontal Disease},
  isbn      = {9780192621207},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  series    = {Oxford medical publications},
  url       = {https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=DbVtQgAACAAJ},
  lccn      = {91027234},
  year      = {1992},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
Periodontitis is a chronic multifactorial inflammatory disease \parencite{caton1989periodontal}.
Periodontal disease is the most common oral condition of human population
\parencite{williams1992pathology}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch from the standard `authoryear` style to `biblatex-ext`'s `ext-authoryear`, a solution can look like this

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkboldoutercitedelims}[1]{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \mkoutercitedelims{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkboldoutercitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}[\mkboldoutercitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkboldoutercitedelims]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkboldouterparencitedelims}[1]{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \mkouterparencitedelims{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkboldouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkboldouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkboldouterparencitedelims]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkboldoutertextcitedelims}[1]{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \mkoutertextcitedelims{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\mkboldoutertextcitedelims]
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}[\mkboldoutertextcitedelims]{\textcite}{}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Worman 2002)" with citations in bold. Name and year are also bold in the bibliography.]

The original definitions of the citations can be found in [`ext-authoryear.cbx`](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/release/ext-authoryear.cbx). Basically we just injected an `\mkbibbold` into the outer delimiter wrapper commands.

For the bibliography we used the name wrapper format `sortname` and `biblatex-ext`'s `biblabeldate` format for the year.

Comment: Worked exactly as it should be and was very accurate

Comment: Please, can I replace the dot after the "year." with the colon ":"

Comment: @DrAdel `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28892/35864.